# Temporary failure in name resolution (PG::ConnectionBad)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, heroku-toolbelt, heroku-postgres

I have Rails 4 application hosted in Heroku EU.

Sice 2 days it's almost impossible for me to start Heroku console. 90 out of 100 tries ends with error like below:

```
scaryguy@ubuntu:~/Sites/xxxxx.com$ heroku run console
Running `console` attached to terminal... up, run.9208
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:825:in `initialize': could not translate host name "ec2-54-221-224-138.compute-1.amazonaws.com" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution (PG::ConnectionBad)
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:825:in `new'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:825:in `connect'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:542:in `initialize'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `new'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `postgresql_connection'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:440:in `new_connection'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:450:in `checkout_new_connection'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:421:in `acquire_connection'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:356:in `block in checkout'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:355:in `checkout'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:265:in `block in connection'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:264:in `connection'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:546:in `retrieve_connection'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:79:in `retrieve_connection'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:53:in `connection'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:203:in `table_exists?'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/acts-as-taggable-on-2.4.1/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/acts_as_taggable_on/cache.rb:5:in `included'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/acts-as-taggable-on-2.4.1/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/taggable.rb:98:in `include'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/acts-as-taggable-on-2.4.1/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/taggable.rb:98:in `taggable_on'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/acts-as-taggable-on-2.4.1/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/taggable.rb:39:in `acts_as_taggable_on'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/acts-as-taggable-on-2.4.1/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/taggable.rb:15:in `acts_as_taggable'
    from /app/app/models/article.rb:6:in `<class:Article>'
    from /app/app/models/article.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:329:in `require_or_load'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:288:in `depend_on'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:206:in `require_dependency'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:465:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:464:in `each'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:464:in `block in eager_load!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:462:in `each'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:462:in `eager_load!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:347:in `eager_load!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `each'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in `require_environment!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:63:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I wonder if this depends on me? Or is this a wide error which Heroku dosn't think to put a notice to their status page, again. I'm not sure because I've been having difficulties with my new installed Ubuntu. Some CA cart issues... But I can connect to anywere at this time... Well, I'm not sure.

I opened a ticket at Heroku yesterday and after 7 hours their answer was "Does problem persist?".

Comment: @RajarshiDas do u experience the same issue?

Comment: I got early same error for heroku I did `uri = URI.parse(domain)`

Comment: Sorry, we're a bit backed up in support at the moment, but you have an update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After me changing my virtual machines and physical OS's DNS settings to use Google DNS, everthing was FIXED!!!!!!

**ALL was a DNS issue...**

I DON'T know who is responsible of this situation? Is it my ISP provider? Who I have to be angry with??

Here is that regular Google DNS settings:

```
8.8.8.8
8.8.4.4
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with DNS resolution of an EC2 server hostname from within a dyno on Heroku.

Unless you've configured some kind of crazy, custom buildpack on your dyno this is likely an ephemeral problem on their end.

Comment: But when I try to connect to heroku console from my windows OS, it connects. No problem... I think this is something with Ubuntu.

Comment: I'm also experiencing this with my Heroku app without any meaningful changes.  This is a bug on their end.

Comment: At the same physical machine, on my host OS -which is Windows- I can connect, but in my guest VM Player hosted OS Ubuntu, I can't... I tried in another HDD installing pure Ubuntu as host OS but problem persists..

Comment: I am also experiencing this problem.  Whilst I can connect via the heroku console, requests that come into the server are unable to write to the database.  Has anyone resolved this or heard from heroku regarding this issue?  Doesn't seem very ephemeral to me...